# How to deploy the broadleaf demo on my own Tomcat server?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, broadleaf-commerce

I was able to start the Broadleaf demo application from the provided scripts adminstart.sh and startsite.sh.  I was also able to change the database to MySQl.  However, I do not understand how to create a war that can run on my Tomcat instance.

I see that broadleaf does things differently as compared to the common approach.  Usually I put the context values into the file application-context. xml that is referred in web.xml.  There is no need for modifying Tomcat context.xml. The example is

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param
```

In the broadleaf configuration there are several context parameters

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>blAdmin.root</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>patchConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/bl-open-admin-contentClient-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-open-admin-contentCreator-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-admin-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-cms-contentClient-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/bl-cms-contentCreator-applicationContext.xml
        classpath*:/blc-config/admin/bl-*-applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-email.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-datasource.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin-filter.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>shutdownHookMethod</param-name>
    <param-value>forceFlush</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Plus in addition in web.xml:

```
<!-- Initialize spring mvc -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-open-admin.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentClient.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-servlet-cms-contentCreator.xml
            classpath:/bl-menu-admin-applicationContext-servlet.xml
            classpath*:/blc-config/admin/bl-*-admin-applicationContext-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet-admin.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The result is that the Tomcat instance contains context.xml in the conf directory that provides database pool configuration:

What is the best way of utilizing broadleaf in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration

- Put your MySQL JDBC driver to tomcat7/lib folder
- Open web.xml for both, site and admin modules in DemoSite
- Add the following code in both web.xml

```xml
<resource-ref>
    <description>WEB</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/web</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <description>STORAGE</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/storage</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <description>SECURE</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/secure</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

- Open cmd prompt for windows or command shell for linux
- Navigate to your JDK_directory/bin and create keystore for SSL switching

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -storepass password
```

- Open Tomcat7/conf/server.xml
- Add the following code to enable SSL switching, just below your default connector port

```xml
<Connector 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="8443" maxThreads="200" 
    scheme="https" secure="true" 
    SSLEnabled="true"
    keystorePass="password" 
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    />
```

- Open Tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml
- Add following

```xml
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

- Populate database.properties with values for your database or
- Configure JNDI for tomcat
- In your admin or site folder there is file target/tomcat-server-config/context.xml.
- Copy this file into tomcat7/conf/
- Open this file and replace the following properties with your database values

```xml
username="${database.user}" : Replace with your database username (eg. broadleaf)
password="${database.password}" : Replace with your database password
driverClassName="${database.driver}" : Replace with your database classname (eg. org.postgresql.Driver)
url="${database.url}" : Replace with your database URL with database path, port and name. (eg. jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/broadleaf)
```

- in your IDE Start Maven project **install** goal of lifecycle (of entire project or each module)
- This will create wars for each module
- Start tomcat (run startup.bat/startup.sh in ~/tomcat7/bin/ )
- Go to app manager and enter tomcat username and key that you added into tomcat-users.xml
- deploy admin and site wars
- context path is url mapping (eg. /admin and /demo-site)
- XML configuration url is full path to your targets context.xml (eg. ~/target/tomcat-server-conf/context.xml)
- WAR directory is full path to your war in target directory
- Don't forget to change **blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** in development.properties from create to update (standalone tomcat have trouble to create tables - that's my expirience with postreSQL)

Comment: Zildyan, did you try these steps and get successful?

Comment: Ofcourse - I spent whole day on it. Maybe I missed something because I wrote answer from memory. You have good start here, search little little more.. If I made it you can do it too ;)